# Excel not to start calculation on Automatic mode if data is put wrong

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want excel to stop calculation if invalid date is put. I tried to use "data Validation" using below formula `=AND(ISNUMBER(E3),LEFT(CELL("format",E3),1)="D")`.
It is working but the calculation don't stop even on wrong data. Which results in `#VALUE!` since my calculations is having some circular references, that's why the calculated values as `#VALUE!` is not reverting back.

Comment: you can't put calculations on hold in excel, you can display different values  (as described in answers already) to show calculation is not appropriate to be done. Now I feel your question is not clear enough, please post screenshots and describe what you have and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if`with `iserror` to get a blank value rather than an error

```
=IF(ISERROR(AND(ISNUMBER(E3),LEFT(CELL("format",E3),1)="D")),"",AND(ISNUMBER(E3),LEFT(CELL("format",E3),1)="D")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need specific error management, than `IFERROR` gives shorter formula compared to `IF` and `ISERROR`:
`=IFERROR(AND(ISNUMBER(E3),LEFT(CELL("format",E3),1)="D"),"")`

Of course, depending on your child formula instead of `""` you may want to get other results (e.g. `FALSE`) in your formula.

Comment: Thanks. my problem is not formula. I just want to stop calculation until the correct date is entered. For example if I am restricting the user to put some value e.g. >20, the calculation related to that specific value shall not be made until the correct value is put.